# How to output data using php from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a blog using mysql to input and output data(blog posts) using php. I have create a table, inserted rows for the data such as: id, title, content and date in "addentry.php". 
I am having problems outputting the data using php on my "viewblog.php". Where it says "//output from table"(line 115), thats where i want to output the data. Ive tried my best to find a solution.

**Thanks in advance.**

---

```js
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<!-- image.html
     A trivial document
     -->
<html xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">


    <head><title> My Blog </title></head>

    <style type ="text/css">

        body{ 

        position: fixed; 
        overflow:overlay;
        width: 100%;
        top: -20px;
        left: -20px;
        right: -40px;
        bottom: -40px;       


        height: auto;
        background-image:url(image.jpg);
        background-size: cover;



        }
        .container{

            background-color: #ecdad6;          
            padding: 30px;
            width:920px;        
            margin-left: 25%;
            padding-bottom:1000px;
            padding-left:0px;
            border: 2px solid black;
            }

        .links{
            position: absolute;

            padding-right: 135px;
            padding-bottom: 800px;              
            margin-left: 680px;
            margin-right: 100px;
            font-size: 20px;
            word-wrap: break-word;
            top:-3px;


        }


        .blog{
            position: absolute;
            width:678px;
            padding-bottom: 920px;              
            margin-left: 10px;
            font-size: 20px;
            text-align: left;            
            word-wrap: break-word;

            }
        ul li { margin-top: -10px; }

        }
        
        iframe{
        border:2px solid black;
        width:4000px;
        display:block;
        *}

    } 
    </style>
    <body>

        <!--Logo & hyperlinked -->
        <p align = "center"><a href="viewblog.php"><img src = "Logo.jpg"      alt="My logo" width="10%" height="10%"/></a></p>
        <br/>
        <hr width="50%">

        <div class="container">                         
            <div class="blog"> 
                <?php
                        
    $host   =   "dbprojects.eecs.qmul.ac.uk"  ;
    $user   =   "hm315"  ;
    $pass   =   "cXtXuyf2pnF4H"  ;
    $db   =   "hm315"  ;
     
    $link  =  mysql_connect ( $host ,  $user ,  $pass );
    if (! $link ) {
        die( 'Could not connect: '  .  mysql_error ());
    }
    echo  'Connected successfully' ;

    $db_selected  =  mysql_select_db ( $db ,  $link );
    if (! $db_selected ) {
        die ( 'Can\'t use $db : '  .  mysql_error ());
    }

    echo  'Connected successfully' ;

    //select from table
           $sql = "SELECT * FROM post02";
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($sql);
    
    echo 'selecting table works';
    
    //output from table
    
    

                             
    //connection + database, record created and close connection.

                if ($link->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
         } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $link->error;
         }
    
                         mysql_close ( $link );
                ?>
                
                
                <form action='index.php' method='get'></form>
                <div class="links">
                    <a href="viewblog.php"> <ul><li>home</li></ul></a> 
                    <a href="login.html"> <ul><li>logIn</li></ul></a> 
                    <a href="entry.html"> <ul><li>add_entry</li></ul></a>                 
                </div>                  
            </div> 
              </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

```html
<?php

  $host   =   "xxx.ac.uk"  ;
 $user   =   "xxx"  ;
 $pass   =   "xxx"  ;
 $db   =   "xxx"  ;
  
 $link  =  mysql_connect ( $host ,  $user ,  $pass, $db );
 if (! $link ) {
     die( 'Could not connect: '  .  mysql_error ());
 }
 echo  'Connected successfully' ;
 

 $db_selected  =  mysql_select_db ( $db ,  $link );
 if (! $db_selected ) {
     die ( 'Can\'t use $db : '  .  mysql_error ());
 }
/*
 // create a table


 $sql="create table  post02(id INT(6) unsigned auto_increment primary key , title varchar(30) not null, content varchar(255) not null, date TIMESTAMP)";



 $connection = mysql_query($sql);

 if (! $connection ) {

     die ( 'Cant create table : '  .  mysql_error ());

 }

  echo  'Created a table successfuly' ;
*/ 

//insert to table
 echo'insert table - initializing';

 if($_POST['submit']){
 $title = $_POST['title'];
 $content = $_POST['content'];
 $date = date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');
 }
 
 $sql = "INSERT INTO post2('title', 'content', 'date') VALUES ($title, $content,$date))";

 if($title =="" || $content=="" ){
     echo "please compelete your post!";
     return;
      
 }
 echo'insert table completed';

    
     mysql_query($db ,$sql);
    header("location: viewblog.php");

 //record created is successful
 if ($link->query($sql) === TRUE) {
     echo "New record created successfully";
 } else {
     echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $link->error;
 }
  
 
mysql_close ( $link );
?>
```

Comment: I hope those are not the real connection creds that you posted. if so, please change user/pass asap. There are many bots that are crawling SO for credentials and will gladly begin mining bitcoins and spamming the world with your credentials within minutes.

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: @lazy_coder I have 2 php files. One named "addentry.php" which creates a table within the database, it also inserts data into the appropriate fields.
I also have another php file called "viewblog.php", this php file fetches the blog posts which is stored in the database table called "post02".
what i need help with, is to try to echo out the stored blog posts from the "post02" table into my "viewblog.php".

Answer (score 1):

The question was not that clear, I wrote a sample code according to the question's title. Oh, and don't forget to change your creds.

```
<table>
<tr>
  <th>Column 1</th>
  <th>Column 2</th>
  <th>Column 3</th>
</tr>

<?php
$r = $link->query("SELECT * FROM table");
while($rf = $r->fetch_assoc())
{
  echo "<tr> 
          <td>{$rf['column_1']}</td>
          <td>{$rf['column_2']}</td>
          <td>{$rf['column_2']}</td>
        </tr>";
}
?>

</table>
```

Comment: I want to be able to fetch data from mysql using php using echo.

Comment: That's exactly what I wrote here.
This code creates a html table with 3 columns and creates the rows from database. Of course you have to change some part of the code (like th names, sql table and column names.